# Unable to show result for executed sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically,I have a pdo prepared statement.It executes but shows no result.This is my code:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

            $query = $_GET['q'];
            if ($query==null) {
                exit('No query');
            }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `uploads_public` WHERE Title =:query ";

        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(":query", $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);




            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
               echo "Your search $query has the following results:<br>";
               $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
               $json = json_encode($results);
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. <br>"; print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
            }
                    // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
        unset($pdo);
        }





   else{
    echo "No input";
}
```

I'm sure that a table `uploads_public` exists ,the row`Title` and there are at least five columns having the value `first`.The name of  the file is `dbselect.php`

But when I run the script `localhost/dbselect.php?q=first`,I get the result:
`Your search first has the following results:`

That's all.It doesn't show the results.It executes but doesn't show the actual results.

I know I'm doing something wrong but I just can't put my finger on it.Please help.

Comment: `echo $json;` maybe???

Comment: I found it @AbraCadaver - eyes not focusing this afternoon.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I can't believe I was that stupid to forget  to echo $json.Thanks.You should probably post this as an answer so I can accept and upvote you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't output the result.

```
echo $json;
```

Or:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```